# Setting folder permissions with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, acl, ownership

I'm trying to change a folders owner by using `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl`. The issues lies when I try to change the `Get-Acl` object by using `.setOwner()` Is this the correct way to change the objects owner property? I am currently using PS 2.0.

```
$DomainNameShort = "domain"
$profileName = "user_name"
$newProfileLocation = "\\server\folder"
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$DomainNameShort\$profileName")
$objFile = Get-Acl $newProfileLocation
$objFile.SetOwner($objUser)
Set-Acl -aclobject $objFile -path $newProfileLocation
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception calling "SetOwner" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated
."
At line:6 char:18
+ $objFile.SetOwner <<<< ($objUser)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you sure the username and domain name are valid when the `ntaccount` object is created ? The error is that it can't verify the existance of the account specified in `$objuser`

Comment: That seems to of done the trick as I was using a pseudo account wile I was testing. Thanks

Comment: be aware that using `set-acl` on a SHARE (not a folder beneath a share, but a share) can break inheritance. Just found that out when testing this in my lab =)  providing solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain or username is incorrect.

`SetOwner()` can verify the identity provided with `$objuser`

**CAUTION** Be aware that using `Set-Acl` on a SHARE (not a folder beneath a share, but the root/share itself) can break inheritance of permissions.